# How To Pass Objects From Node To Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

The problem I'm having is with passing the object from Node.js to the database (MySQL).

currently, I'm using the INSERT method which only allows me to pass strings, if I try to pass an object I get an error

Here is what I'm using right now :

```
let new_movie_data = `INSERT INTO testing (name, last) VALUES ('Jhonee','Mel')`

connection.query(new_movie_data, function (err, result){
  if(err) throw (err)
})
```

This is what I get from react and want to send to the database :

```
{
name:"Jhonee",
last:"Mel"
}
```

trying to put this in the "VALUES" will cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the JSON in to its components:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(stringFromReact);
const new_movie_data = 'INSERT INTO testing (name, last) VALUES (?, ?);
connection.query(new_movie_data, [jsonObj.name, jsonObj.last], function (err, result){
  if(err) throw (err)
});
```